# Connect Xamarin to DB

Tags: visual-studio, rest, web-services, sql-server-2008, xamarin.forms

I'm starting learning Xamarin and i face problem in connecting app with DB. i built rest web services with method get and i uplode it in host. after that i add this code in app

```
private async Task<List<testClass>> GetlistAsync()
        {
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("my web service link", string.Empty));
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            List<testClass> Items = new List<testClass>();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<testClass>>(content);
            }
            return Items;
        }
```

the problem is whenever i add run. the code will stop after httpclint. getasync line without doing lines after it 
pleas help as fast as possible 
thanks

Comment: have you verified connectivity between your device/emulator and your server?  Hint: use the browser ON THE DEVICE (or emulator) to test

Comment: yes and it is connect but still the code is not working

Comment: Are there any errors when the codes stop ?

Comment: no and that why i don't understand. i tray to test the code in web application mvc and it works fine but when i tray it in xamarin form app it doesn't work

Comment: Try to use `var response = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` instead of `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);`